# change https proxy settings of android studio

Tags: android, gradle, https, proxy, dependencies

I changed android studio http and https proxy setting to use it in my university. Now i cant find https settings, changed http settings but still cant resolve dependencies as they use https. Anyone knows how to change https proxy settings?

Answer (score 3):

It took me several hours to find solution for this, But I finally found out it not part of Android Studio preferences, but it's configured in "gradle.properties" of project.

```
systemProp.https.proxyPort=11111
systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.http.proxyPort=11111
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Edit proxy settings in the following places.

1. File > Settings > System settings > HTTP Proxy
2. Project gradle.properties
3. ~/.gradle/gradle.properties